# Python: split method call into multiple lines

Tags: python

In JavaScript I can do something like:

```
var template = "{a}{b}-{c}{d}";
var myStuff = template
                .replace("{a}", a)
                .replace("{b}", b)
                .replace("{c}", c)
                .replace("{d}", d);
```

I would like to do something similar in python, but due to the fact that python uses indentation for blocks of code, I can't simply write:

```
myStuff = template
                .replace("{a}", a)
                .replace("{b}", b)
                .replace("{c}", c)
                .replace("{d}", d)
```

I don't want to have to write this:

```
myStuff = template.replace("{a}", a).replace("{b}", b).replace("{c}", c).replace("{d}", d)
```

Or this:

```
myStuff = template
myStuff = myStuff.replace("{a}", a)
myStuff = myStuff.replace("{b}", b)
myStuff = myStuff.replace("{c}", c)
myStuff = myStuff.replace("{d}", d)
```

They both look ugly (and I don't like my code ugly!).
Is there a way to break a method call chain into new lines in python, just like I did in JavaScript?

Comment: there is .format for that :) `myStuff = template.format(x=x, a=a, b=b)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Other answers would get you how to split a statement into multiple lines, But an easier way to achieve what you are doing would be to use `str.format()` -

```
>>> template = "{a}{b}-{c}{d}"
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 2
>>> c = 3
>>> d = 4
>>> template.format(**{'a':a,'b':b,'c':c,'d':d})
'12-34'
>>> template.format(a=a,b=b,c=c,d=d)
'12-34'
```

The first `str.format()` unpacks a dictionary into keyword arguments for the function `format()` (similar to what the second one does directly) .

---

Also, you can split the arguments to a function call in multiple lines without having to use `\` , Example -

```
>>> template.format(a=a,
...                 b=b,
...                 c=c,
...                 d=d)
'12-34'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Format looks nice, but my variable names are quite long (a, b, c, d were just examples) so I would end up with a really long line of code anyway :/

Comment: @DanielGruszczyk did you want to provide a more realistic example for your use-case then?

Comment: I guess I can, just like shown in the other answer :)

Comment: Ok cool , also one more thing to note, you can split the arguments for a single function call into multiple lines without having to use `\` .

Comment: Thanks, this is a good point, and imo better approach than chaining replace :)

Comment: @DanielGruszczyk chaining replace is going to be much less efficient than using `str.format`... Also - depending on context and if you have a direct mapping of variable names, then you can use something like: `'{foo}{bar}-{spam}{whatever}'.format(**locals())`

Comment: I really donno why this is the accepted answer. The question was about how to split method chaining into multiple lines and the answer talks about this specific problem of string formatting. If I were to chain other methods like reverse or sort into multiple lines, this answer won't help me. But, my question is the same.

Answer (score 20):

In general your only hope is to use line joining. You can always use explicit line joining

```
myStuff = template \
            .replace("{a}", a) \
            .replace("{b}", b) \
            .replace("{c}", c) \
            .replace("{d}", d)
```

To use implicit line joining you have to come up with somewhere to put parenthesis (implicit line joining is when you have something within paretheses, brackets or braces - if split over several lines the identation does not take effect). For example

```
 myStuff = (template.replace("{a}", a)
            .replace("{b}", b)
            .replace("{c}", c)
            .replace("{d}", d))
```

Then of course you can probably find special solutions for specific situations, like using string formatting in your example:

```
 myStuff = template.format(a=a, b=b, c=c, d=d)
```

but that will not work if you're trying to replace something entirely else (it also doesn't fail if `a`, `b`, `c` or `d` happens to be something else than a string).

Answer (score 5):

You can use `\` to break a line:

```
s = s.replace('a', 'x')\
      .replace('b', 'y')\
      .replace('c', 'z')
```

Or you can create a generic function that accepts a dictionary of old and new values, replaces them all with a for loop and returns the new string.